# Двойное двоеточие перед функцией в С++

Tags: c++

Операция двойного двоеточия называется операцией разрешения области видимости.
Когда мы пишем `::func()` (слева от оператора ничего нет), мы уточняем принадлежность к области видимости глобального пространства имён? Зачем?

Comment: Например, вы находитесь в некотором пространстве имён, скажем, `std`, где у вас уже есть `func()`. Если, находясь внутри этого пространства, просто написать `func()`, будет вызвана функция из пространства `std` : `std::func()`. А вам нужна другая `func()`, которая определена в глобальной области: `::func()`.

Comment: для уточнения принадлежности имени к глобальному пространству имен

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Допустим, Ваш код работает в пространстве имён `ns1`, внутри которого есть функция `ns1::func()`, но при этом Вам нужно вызвать функцию `func()`, определённую без пространства имён (в глобальном пространстве). Вот в таких случаях Вам и нужно использовать `::func()`, ибо без этого уточнения компилятор вызовет `ns1::func()`, чего Вам не хотелось бы.

Answer (score 8):

Правила поиска имен (name lookup) в С++ очень сильно отличаются для случая квалифицированных имен (т.е. с явным указанием класса или пространства имен) и неквалифицированных имен (без такого указания). Если вас чем-то не устраивает поведение неквалифицированного поиска, которое сложно, многоэтажно и включает в себя массу нюансов вроде ADL, то вы можете подавить это поведение путем указания квалифицированного имени.

В частности, в качестве частного примера, вам может понадобиться вызвать функцию `::func` там, где ее имя скрыто локальной переменной `int func;`.